# Set radio button values on dynamically created fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can you check if a radio button is selected and then assign it a value when these fields are created dynamically.

This is the JQuery I tried:

```
$('#want').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('.from-group').
        val(($('#want').is(':checked')) ? "yes" : "no");
    var ans=$(this).val();
    alert(ans);
});
```

But it doesn't set a value for the dynamic fields as shown in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/1rkhn7ek/32/).

Comment: Please post your HTML as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to delegate your event like this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Amin52J/1rkhn7ek/33/)**

```
$(document).on('change','#want',function() {
    $(this).closest('.from-group').
    val(($('#want').is(':checked')) ? "yes" : "no");
    var ans=$(this).val();
    alert(ans);
});
```

also remember that **ids must be unique**, your code generates duplicated ids

Comment: Does this set the value of the radio button to either yes or no....at the moment it still returns a blank value?